# Independent realizations deifnition

Tags: statistics

> Let $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ be two **independent realizations** of the
>   random variable Y.

What is meant by independent realizations? I thought only random variables could be independent between each other. Also why does this imply $E(Y_{1})=E(Y_{2})=E(Y)$ and the same for variance?

Comment: In maths, this means that the distribution of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is $P_Y\otimes P_Y$. In English, this means that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and both distributed as $Y$. Which should answer the question in the last sentence of your post.

Comment: I think this is what is often referred to as "i.i.d." RVs (independent identically distributed RVs)

Comment: @MPW, thanks for your answer. Does this mean that the random variable $Y$ takes on values $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ with 0.5 probability for each?

Comment: Wow. *Not at all*. Did you read my comment?

Comment: @Did, ya but I didn't get it :/

Comment: try this example, suppose we take 2 people independently and randomly and ask their height, then the height of those two people are the realization (the $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in your case), however, since both of those people belong to same population (we can say belong to same distribution of rv $Y$), then the expected values of them are also same, i hope this is clear, Let me know if you still doubt about something :-)

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki, I see! That clears it up thank you.

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki: This sounds like you intend $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be samples of $Y$, so they are in fact not random variables but sample values. This is not the same thing as saying that they are iid RVs

Comment: I understand, thank you for reminding me, I know the one I gave is not the definition, @Sadem, if you look for the definition, you can see Did's comment, because the one I gave is just the intuition and example of it, not the exact definition

Comment: And when you don't "get" something, you stay silent? But when a dangerously imprecise characterization is proposed (sorry @Rizky...) then you instantly "get" it? Well, well... In this case I would suggest to *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that

1. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are *independent*, i.e., $P(Y_1<a \;\&\;Y_2<b)=P(Y_1<a)\times P(Y_2<b)$.
2. $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are distributed like $Y$, i.e., $P(Y_1<a)=P(Y_2<a)=P(Y<a)$.